# Display visitors Geolocation and address popup using Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I currently have some JavaScript code embedded in a Joomla page that displays the visitors location when they enable Sharing of their Location. I would also like to popup the address beside the location icon. I've taken the original code I had for geolocation and tried to insert another piece of code to popup the address but to no avail. The combined code I have is displayed below. I hope someone can help me and I would very much appreciate it:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js?ver=3.1.2" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function init() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker();
            marker.setPosition(myLatlng);
            marker.setMap(map);

            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': myLatlng}, function(results, status) { 
            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { if(results[0]) {
                $('#address_current').text(results[0].formatted_address); 
            } 
            else { 
                alert('No results found'); 
            } 
        } 
        else { 
            var error = { 'ZERO_RESULTS': 'We Could Not Find Your Address' }  
            $('#address_new').html('' + error[status] + ''); } }); 
    }, function() {
            alert("Your browser does not support Geolocation. Update to Google Chrome or Firefox");
        });
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

Comment: I get  a javascript error with the posted code `Uncaught ReferenceError: geocoder is not defined`; if I fix that and add the required HTML, it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a javascript error with the posted code Uncaught ReferenceError: geocoder is not defined; if I fix that and add the required HTML, it works for me.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qsu1ghkc/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
function init() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker();
            marker.setPosition(myLatlng);
            marker.setMap(map);

            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': myLatlng}, function(results, status) { 
            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { if(results[0]) {
                $('#address_current').text(results[0].formatted_address); 
            } 
            else { 
                alert('No results found'); 
            } 
        } 
        else { 
            var error = { 'ZERO_RESULTS': 'We Could Not Find Your Address' }  
            $('#address_new').html('' + error[status] + ''); } }); 
    }, function() {
            alert("Your browser does not support Geolocation. Update to Google Chrome or Firefox");
        });
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

```css
html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="address_current"></div>
<div id="map" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Really appreciated